# Android GCM send multiple message to device

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I kinda stuck on a problem. I need to send message notification and alert notification to the device. Message notification is sent when a user send message to other and alert notification is generated to alert user from server. That mean I need multiple notification types. I am using this on my server to push notification to my device.

```
// This is code from the class that take user input
$notify = "This is message"
$msg = array("Message" => $notify);
$sense = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $msg);

//This is the send notification in GCM class
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

How can I adjust the above code to meet my requirement. I tried by sending

```
$fields = array(

    "registration_ids" : registatoin_ids,
    "data" : {
        "type" : "Message",
        "Message" : $message,
    }

     );
```

But I got error as

```
 E/JSON(3444): <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in <b>/home/a8709494/public_html/mobile/GCM.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `=>` operator for this:

```
$fields = array(
  "registration_ids" => "registatoin_ids",
  "data" => array(
    "type" => "Message",
    "Message" => $message,
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks It worked but I need to put `'registration_ids'` on a single quote and I received message as `Received: Bundle[{android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=xxxxxxxxxxxx, type=Message, Message={"Message":"From : Me to you."}}]
` again why it didn't worked with double quote . and how can I now work this string on client side. I have GCMIntentService imlemented as `private void sendNotification(String msg)` and I am getting `msg = ""Message":"From : Me to you."}"`

Comment: You can use the same technique that you already used: Define several nested arrays to achieve that. Single quotes will make no-substitution if you're passing a variable, just double-quotes will expand the value of a variable. Once you achieve your goal, both for reputation and feedback, don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most from within all you might get until then.